# Java using instanceof but based on method argument

Tags: java, object, instanceof

I have 3 objects

```
Car
SmallCar extends Car
LargeCar extends Car
```

Using this method i want to count cars of specific type in a list:

```
public int availableCars(String carType) {
    int count = 0;
    for (Car i : fleet) {
        if (i instanceof SmallCar) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

What is the best way to pass the carType given (if it is as String or something else that would be better) to have something like:

```
if (i instanceof carTypeGiven)
```

The method returns how many cars of specific type are available.

Comment: Then you need two int count variables, smallCarCount and largeCarCount. The total count will be their sum of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in the class instead of a string indicating the desired type. You can limit it to subclasses of `Car` using wildcards like this: `Class<? extends Car>`

```
public int availableCars(Class<? extends Car> carType) {
    int count = 0;
    for (Car car : fleet) {
        if (carType.isInstance(car)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Use [`Class.isInstance(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-) to determine if a car in the fleet is of the desired type.

It is also possible to do this more concisely with Java 8's streams (assuming `fleet` is a collection):

```
public long availableCars(Class<? extends Car> carType) {
    return fleet.stream().filter(carType::isInstance).count();
}
```

If `fleet` is an array, you would need to do it slightly differently:

```
public long availableCars(Class<? extends Car> carType) {
    return Arrays.stream(fleet).filter(carType::isInstance).count();
}
```

Note that I have changed the return type to `long` since that's what [`Stream.count()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--) returns. You could keep the return type as `int` and cast the result from `count()` to an `int`, as well.

Comment: +1 for the inclusion of Java 8 streams to do this sort of filtering!